# nslookup is showing different ip address for subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, nslookup, dns-lookup

I recently moved my web service to a new host. In the new host when my clients access www they get a message saying the SSL is not correct. Under my investigation, I found a problem with the name mistake.

My certificate is not working with [www.myofferweb.com](http://www.myofferweb.com), but it is working fine with myofferweb.com.

Under my investigation as well, I found *nslookup* is showing different IP address when I "trace" to myofferweb.com and when I do the same thing to [www.myofferweb.com](http://www.myofferweb.com)

How can I fix it? Is it only about cache in the DNS servers?

**Update**

[myofferweb.com](https://myofferweb.com)

Comment: "My certificate is not working with www, but it is working fine" For some definition of "not working" it "just" means that you forgot to put both names in the certificate SAN part. So you will need to issue another certificate with both names.

Comment: If `traceroute` is showing a different IP for the two names, it is more likely either a DNS misconfiguration or caching issue, not a certificate problem.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the question, the IP addresses for `myofferweb.com` and `www.myofferweb.com` are different.  This appears to be in the DNS and not a caching issue.

You can check whether it is a caching issue by looking at the NS records for the domain,

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
myofferweb.com.         3453    IN      NS      ns41.domaincontrol.com.
myofferweb.com.         3453    IN      NS      ns42.domaincontrol.com.
```

and querying those nameservers directly.

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
myofferweb.com.         3600    IN      A       191.233.203.34
```

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.myofferweb.com.     600     IN      A       184.168.131.241
```

The solution (assuming the web server is configured correctly - that could be a second problem) is to change whichever of these two records is incorrect in the DNS.

Answer (score 1):

Your question itself says that when you do nslookup it's not resolving correct ip address . So please check with A record configuration in your respective dns server . Ensure correct A record is created mapping server ip address to url or

Post above mentioned changes then check with SSL certificate status .